# Communist brain, 5 people sharing one mind

Tags: humans, brain

**Her**: Greg I had enough of your sh*t! Why did you do that? What the hell was in your mind?!
**Him**: our*, our mind.

That was just a stupid joke, forgive my stupid humor, but imagine if different individuals actually shared one mind and not in the sense of a hive mind where every entity has a different mind but is controlled by a stronger one, but more like a single brain controlling more bodies.

Where only one body has a brain and the rest of the bodies just follow instructions, like bots or NPC's.

Say Greg has 5 bodies, but only one of them is the real Greg, the remaining ones are just empty souless bodies that follow basic instructions.

However sometimes the bodies mess up or misunderstend commands from the main body.

Like crafting an entire new bed when asked to make the bed or or going into tilt repeating one task until told to stop by the main body.

Those occurrences are rare, but they happen.

The bodies have a small brain like organ where they register everything they see and then upload the video file into the main Greg's brain which is translated as an instant photographic like memory.

The main Greg can give basic daily commands or even specific commands sometimes to the other bodies but needs to be in direct contant with other bodies when giving commands and can't control them from a distance.

Like : every two days attend class, except Saturdays and Sundays, use this calendar to know what day it is.

But all 5 bodies are made out of organic matter, they are not robots.

What mechanism does Greg use to command his bodies and upload their visive "memory" onto himself?

Comment: Seems like you have invented a non-technofetish version of The Borg. However, the reason The Borg need their technofetish is precisely to make such remote control possible. So i guess you have narrowed it to Telepathy and Magic. Taking direct control sequentially to feed, excrete, and bathe five bodies seems a bit too time-consuming and tedious to have much adventure.

Comment: So Greg has these four other bodies that report things to him, and take instructions, but aren't perfect about it... I think those are known as *employees*.

Comment: Hi Vermin, you've created something interesting here, but you will need to be much more specific in defining a question based upon your creation.  "How can I make this work?" is not very clear.  Are you asking about their origin story, their method of information transfer, how they keep their multiplicity secret, or even what happens when one of the drones are killed?  Keep in mind, you are only supposed to ask one question per post.

Comment: 5 people form a community? I think you might want to use another term like Gestalt. See Theodore Sturgeon novel : More Than Human

Comment: "What mechanisms" is not much of an improvement (if any) on "How can I make this work".  What technologies are available to him ?  What is the nature of the bodies : mechanical, biological ?  Are they independent entities of their own or are they basically just robots that act on commands issued ?  How high level is the command and execution ?  Is it step by step, practically do it yourself or is it issue top level abstract command and the unit does the rest as best it can ?